# How does this dynamic import part of code works?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I want to. retry my js dynamic import if it failed. I found 1 solution here - [How to manually load webpack async chunks, when any dynamic import fails to load file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56772771/how-to-manually-load-webpack-async-chunks-when-any-dynamic-import-fails-to-load)

```
function retry(fn, retriesLeft = 5, interval = 1000) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fn()
      .then(resolve)
      .catch((error) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          if (retriesLeft === 1) {
            // reject('maximum retries exceeded');
            reject(error);
            return;
          }

          // Passing on "reject" is the important part
          
          //HOW DOES THIS PART OF CODE WORKS? WHY WE NEED THEN CALLBACK WITH resolve, reject callbacks?
          retry(fn, retriesLeft - 1, interval).then(resolve, reject);
        }, interval);
      });
  });
}
```

(we called retry function which return new promise) HOW DOES THIS PART OF CODE WORKS? WHY WE NEED ".then" CALLBACK WITH resolve, reject callbacks?

why we need

```
.then(resolve, reject);
```

this construction?

Is it really necessary to update the state (rejected) of the promise to work from outside?

Comment: The setTimeout of 1000 ms needs a callback, because it "breaks" the Promise chain, and the code - as it is set up - throws an error after five retries. The `.then(resolve, reject)` is the only thing that ties the setTimeout to the previous Promise.

Comment: Your code has the [Explicit Promise Construction Antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it)! (Only the `setTimeout` part should be wrapped in `new Promise`)

Comment: @FZs, How can i change it if i want to use it with react.lazy?

Comment: Why not just use dynamic `import()`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/import#importing_on-demand_in_response_to_user_action

Comment: @RickardElimää, Thank You, but i do not fully understand, does a promise change its status if it is rejected at least once?

Comment: @RickardElimää, i want to have retry load logic

Comment: No, but you can create a method that does dynamic imports, and then just call that method again in a catch.

Comment: @RickardElimää That's probably what `fn()` does in OP's code.

Comment: @RickardElimää, i want to use it declaratively (as React component) this function will be in react component

Comment: @user469485 You can just wrap a call to `retry` in `React.lazy`, and you should be good.

Answer (score 0):

Reduce the clutter to see the core logic. Without forwarding the resolve/reject functions in some way, only the top-level call will resolve via `.then`.

```js
function retry(fn) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fn()
      .then(resolve)
      .catch((error) => {
        /* this call does not return to catch. data is lost */
        retry(fn)
      });
  });
}

retry(foo).then(/* */)
```

As other have pointed out, `setTimeout` inside a promise handler is dangerous because throwing in the callback does not bubble into the promise chain.